# virtualenv and CLI tools

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm aware of how to use virtualenv for isolating Python dependencies in a long-running script, like a Flask or Twisted app. But I've been sort of puzzled about how you're supposed to go about this for a script intended to be invoked from the command line.

Suppose I wanted to make a CLI tool for interacting with some API, perhaps using Click or docopt. Obviously you don't want to have to `source venv/bin/activate` every time you want to use this tool. But I'd assume that it's still best to still use virtualenv to keep a clean environment even beyond development.

Sorry for the newbie question, but...what are you supposed to do to package up a script so it can be cleanly used in this manner? (I'm more used to RubyGems, and am still figuring out Pip and VirtualEnv.)

Answer (score 3):

In general, if a package you've installed in a virtual env that provides binary command line script, say in `~/.virtualenv/bin/` you can symlink it into `~/bin/` (or wherever on your path you'd like to put local scripts).

There are a couple projects that aim to solve this issue:

- [pipsi](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/pipsi) the pip script installer -- amounts to doing the virtual env creation and symlinking for you
- [pipx](https://github.com/pipxproject/pipx) pip for executable binaries

Comment: now there is another project https://github.com/pipxproject/pipx which is cool and solves the problem in question. So it should be an accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

An excellent article on virtualenv by Dabapps would make it clear for you:
http://www.dabapps.com/blog/introduction-to-pip-and-virtualenv-python/

As for invoking it from a CLI script: 
 1. cd to your project root
 2. env/bin/python your_main_file.py (Assuming your virtualenv is named env)

This way you don't need to source the virtualenv everytime.

Comment: There is no need to cd to the project root. You can directly run /opt/myproject/env/bin/python /opt/myproject/myproject.py. For convenience you can create an alias or a 1-line shellscript.

Answer (score -1):

Each virtualenv has it's own Python site_packages, builtin modles, and Python interpreter. So virtualenv is **meant to be used at the project level**, not at the "package by package" level. It isolates a collection of Python modules and possible dependencies. Each virtualenv has it's own location where pip will install packages. In theory, virtualenv should not be necessary, but in practice, it's nice to have a way to have different "environments" with different versions of Python modules and Python interpreters. I don't know if Ruby has something similar, that would allow you to have different "sets" of gems for different projects.

People that use straight virtualenv will add aliases to their `.bashrc`, for example:

```
alias workonawesomeproject="source ~/venv/awesomeproject/bin/activate"
```

They would activate the virtualenv with the alias

```
workonawesomeproject
```

To leave a virtualenv you use the command `deactivate`

An easier way to deal with virtualenvs is to use `virtualenvwrapper`

`pip install virtualenvwrapper`

Add these lines to your `.bashrc` (or other shell initialization file)

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/venv # this directory is your choice
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/src # this directory is your choice
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh # leave this alone
```

If you just modified your `.bashrc` make sure to source it

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then to make a new virtualenv you simply run

```
mkvirtualenv awesomeproject
```

To use that virtualenv

```
workon awesomeproject
```

To deactivate that virtualenv

```
deactivate
```

Virtualenvwrapper Docs:
http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html